# SQL Server - update column where <set of columns> not in <other table>

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I have two tables `Main` and `Other` like the following:

```
                    Main
+----------+-----------------------------------+
|  Field1  |  <set of other columns...>        |
+----------+-----------------------------------+
|   NULL   |           ...                     |
|   NULL   |           ...                     |
|   NULL   |           ...                     |


                          Other
           +-----------------------------------+
           |  <same set of other columns...>   |
           +-----------------------------------+
           |           ...                     |
           |           ...                     |
           |           ...                     |
```

Is there a concise way to update `Main.Field1` where the rest of the columns, taken together, are not in a row of `Other`?

In other words, I want to update `Field1` for each row in

```
SELECT <set of other columns...> FROM Main
   EXCEPT
SELECT <same set of other columns...> FROM Other
```

---

Dynamic SQL is an option, but I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to do something like this.

Comment: Can you give a better example? As in, taken straight from your application?

Comment: Sure, I'll try to make it more concrete.  There's a lot of overhead information that doesn't really have anything to do with the question, so I had tried to abstract it out, but I guess I went too far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really wanted to you could use the Except clause

```
UPDATE m
SET field = 'AValue'
FROM 
   MAIN  m
   INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM MAIN
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM OTHER ) t
on m.PK = t.PK
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e476/6)

You should note that the use of  `*` here is very fragile and you should explicitly set your field list. It also assumes that the joining fields (PK) are available in both Main and Other and  they would be the same

Other wise you're much better off using NOT EXISTS or an ANTI-JOIN (LEFT/ISNULL)

```
UPDATE m
   SET Field1 = 'foo'
FROM 
   Main m
   LEFT JOIN 
     Other o
    ON m.FIELD2 = o.FIELD2
    AND m.FIELD3 = o.FIELD3
WHERE 
   o.PK is null
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e476/8)

Comment: Shouldn't the first line be `UPDATE sc`? I've always used the alias there. (And also `on sc.PK = t.PK`.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I've always used the table name in the UPDATE and not the alias. I can't say why and can't think of a good reason . Is it arbitrary ?

Comment: It can be quite important if it's a self-join. I was actually surprised that your fiddle worked.

Comment: @AaronBertrand well I can't remember the last time I did an update  with a self-join in there... but I guess its better to avoid it and use the alias.

Comment: I ended up using a modified version of your first query here, so I'm accepting this one.  I had thought to try joining the table to itself, and subquerying with an `EXCEPT` statement, but I hadn't thought to try the two together.

Answer (score 1):

```
update m
set ...
from Main m
where not exists(select * from Other where <columns-equal>)
```

This translates to a left-anti-semi-join.

You could also use a left join but that translates to a normal left-join-plus-filter which is slightly less efficient. This looks like an optimizer weakness.

Comment: And the part where you do the `UPDATE`?

Comment: Oh I overlooked that requirement. I added it.